# Convert a file to JSON

Tags: java, json, fileparsing

I have a file in the following format:

```
TEST1 =
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL= TCP)(Host= test100.xyz.com)(Port= 1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = TEST1))
)
TEST2 =
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL= TCP)(Host= test101.xyz.com)(Port= 1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = TEST2))
)
```

Is there a library which I can use to parse it and store as JSON?

Comment: Given that the format does not appear to be a standard you will have to write code to parse it yourself.

Comment: Also asking for a library is off topic

Answer (score -2):

You can try around below code -

```
File file=new File("D:\\tnames.txt");
    String str=FileUtils.readFileToString(file);

    str = str.replace("(", "{");
    str = str.replace(")", "}");
    str = str.replace("=", ":");

    String jsonString = "{" + str + "}";
    System.out.println(jsonString);
```

Comment: Err... no. It wouldn't work. For example in this line `(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL= TCP)(Host= test100.xyz.com)(Port= 1521))`